# Are review and critique questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

- On Stack Overflow, code review questions are off-topic and are migrated to CodeReview.SE.
- On Programmers.SE, questions asking to review a particular architecture or design are mostly on-topic (unless too specific).
- On Photo.SE, I believe questions asking for review and critique are off-topic. I've never seen there any question posting a photo and simply asking for critique. There are other websites, especially [1x](http://1x.com/), where the person can receive [mostly] constructive critique.

What about Video.SE? Can I post a link to a video I've done and ask for constructive critique?

If not, what can I do to improve my skills, given that books won't necessarily tell me that I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My view would be that such review would be off topic for the same reason it is on photography.  While there are strong best practices and objective arguments towards ways to improve code, the visual arts is just that, art.  It is highly subjective and there isn't a right or wrong answer for many aspects of it.  They inherently need to be discussions in order to be productive which is not what the SE Q/A platform is designed to handle.

What I would encourage is the same thing I encourage on Photography.SE.  If you want a critique, jump in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12905/video-production) and post your work there.  Video.SE chat isn't as active as Photography, but it still gets fairly regularly monitored by a number of people who can provide insights there, in a format much more designed to handle the back and forth discussion typical of a productive arts critique.

Comment: Good point; the subjectivity makes it indeed badly suited for a Q&A format. As for your suggestion to use chat, I checked it before asking this question and it seemed to me that it's not very active (last message by you a month ago), but still, I'll post some videos for review there when they are ready.

Comment: @MainMa - yeah, the thing with SE chat is that there are a few of us on the site that are in the chat system regularly and have it favorited.  I'm in SE.chat several hours a day at least on average and check it a few times a day, so if you post something in chat, you normally get a response within a couple hours.  I'm also not the only one to do this.